# Is it possible to show all files in all subfolders in one buffer?

Tags: dired

Emacs 26.1, Windows 10, dired+

Suppose I has folder with 2 subfolders. In every folders has files. Is it possible , to show all files in one buffers.
Smt like this:

[image]

P.S.
If I use `"i"` (`dired-maybe-insert-subdir`)  in dired mode

[image]

it's not good, because I need to **press 4 times** to open all folders.
But I want with ONE press to show all folders/files and all its subfolders and files.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `dired-aux`, which is built-in in Emacs and you can easily require in your init file, you can then press <kbd>i</kbd> on a directory in a Dired buffer and have its contents displayed in the current buffer.

<kbd>i</kbd> is `dired-maybe-insert-subdir`. As per the documentation (<kbd>C-h k i</kbd>):

> Insert this subdirectory into the same dired buffer.
>
> If it is already present, just move to it (type M-x dired-do-redisplay
>   to refresh),   else inserts it at its natural place (as ls -lR would
>   have done). With a prefix arg, you may edit the ls switches used for
>   this listing.   You can add R to the switches to expand the whole tree
>   starting at   this subdirectory. This function takes some pains to
>   conform to ls -lR output.

If you do <kbd>C-u i</kbd> in the parent directory, you will see all the sub-directories in the buffer. In your example, move up one directory, press <kbd>C-u i</kbd> on `TEMP` and add the `-R` switch.

Comment: Not good.  I updated my post

Comment: As per the quoted documentation, if you do `C-u i` in the parent directory, you will see all the sub-directories in the buffer. In your example, move up one directory, press `C-u i` on `TEMP` and add the `-R` switch.

Comment: @ManuelUberti: Now that OP has updated the question to say that `i` is not sufficient, please integrate your last comment into your answer, as I think it answers the question. Thx.

Comment: Oh sure, you're right. Done.

Answer (score 0):

[Subdirectories in Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Subdirectories-in-Dired.html)

> The simplest way to include multiple directories in one Dired buffer is to specify the options `-lR` for running `ls`. (If you give a numeric argument when you run Dired, then you can specify these options in the minibuffer.) That produces a recursive directory listing showing all subdirectories at all levels.

[Dired and `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-and-Find.html)

> To search for files with names matching a wildcard pattern use `M-x find-name-dired`. It reads arguments *directory* and *pattern*, and chooses all the files in *directory* or its subdirectories whose individual names match *pattern*.